# Greater than the number of total male

Tags: vb.net

I'm still running the program but when I run it, if I enter a number in the textbox, the messagebox was shown also.

How to write a good code for that - when if I have a total of Male and I will input the number of indigenous and if it is greater than the total of male the message box.

Please help what is the correct code for it.

```
Private Sub TxtIM_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtIM.TextChanged
        If TxtMTotal.Text > TxtMTotal.Text Then
            MessageBox.Show("Must be Greater Than Total of Male")
        End If



    End Sub

Private Sub TxtIM_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtIM.TextChanged
        If TxtMTotal.Text > TxtMTotal.Text Then
            MessageBox.Show("Must be Greater Than Total of Male")
        End If



    End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing you should be doing is working with numbers and not text. If you use `Strings`, "10" is less than "2". Secondly, you might think about comparing two different values rather than one value with itself. Put some thought into the logic first. How would you do it if you were using pen and paper? Write down the answer to that question. Now, write code to implement what you just wrote down. Don't try to write code when you don't even know what it's supposed to do. That's how you end up with nonsense.

Comment: please give me a sample code on how to fix it, because txtMtotal is the total of the sum of the 2 textboxes sir/maam while the txtMtotal.text will input the user and if the user input is greater than to the value of the sum of 2 inputed textboxes or it will shown in TxtTotal.text and the messagebox will show.

Comment: What don't you understand about the sample code you found when made the effort to look for some on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are trying to compare `String` types and not `Integer types.

When VB.Net is comparing two `Integer` types, it compares the numbers to see which is bigger. No problem.

But. When comparing strings, it compares by individual characters. Let's say that you have two strings .. "9" and "31". VB will look at the 1st character "9" and compare it with the first character "1" in the second string. The character code for 9 is 57 and the ascii code for 1 is 49. As soon as VB.net finds a difference, it will stop comparing the rest of the string. Your second string could be "31543543" and VB will still see "9" as bigger.

To solve your problem you need to make sure that VB is comparing numbers and not characters. To do this there are several ways.

The simplest for your purposes is

```
If Integer.Parse(TxtMTotal.Text) > Integer.Parse(TxtMTotal.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Must be Greater Than Total of Male")
End If
```

Comment: Still comparing `TxtMTotal.Text` with itself :) The converted content, in this case. Maybe, the OP was trying to compare the content of `TxtMTotal` and `TxtIM`.

Comment: @jimi Ah duh :)) How did I miss that? What year is it again?